# How to Get time 2 Hours from current time in IONIC

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to book a vehicle.So i get date.BUt i didnt got the time.Actually i want to book at least 2 hours after current time.also i need to get full time from next day onwards please help me.Iam doing in Ionic framework and AngularJS

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Question and technology not clear from the question.Please explain the scenarion

Comment: @AlbinJoseph Thanks For your Comment.I need to book a vehicle.So i get date.BUt i didnt got the time.Actually i want to book at least 2 hours after current time.also i need to get full time from next day onwards please help me.Iam doing in Ionic framework and AngularJS

Answer (score 3):

```
var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
var twoHoursIntoFuture = new Date(time + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2);
```

the `new Date()` creates a new date object from current time. `getTime()` gets the time in milliseconds since January 1st, 1970. Then we just add 2 hours into `timeNow` (1000 * 60 * 60 * 2 milliseconds) and make a new date object based on that.

Check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp for more date manipulation info.

Comment: Please give me answer with angularJs.I didnt get it now also

Answer (score 0):

```
this.myActualDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).toISOString().toString().substring(0, 10);

this.myMaxDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (368 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).toISOString();


 <ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY/MM/DD" pickerFormat="YYYY MMMM DDDD" min={{myActualDate}} max={{myMaxDate}} [(ngModel)]="myActualDate"
          formControlName="booking_date" class="flex-date" required></ion-datetime>
```

You can modify this code to perform yours.

If you want to extend three days in actual date then you can edit 365 digit into 368.
It will add three days in your date.

I think it will also work for time.
If you edit hours , minutes and seconds.